# How to send data in header using RestTemplate

Tags: rest

I have three fields: `SystemId`, `RegionCode` and `Locale`. I have to send these three fields in header using RestTemplate. I'm using this code:

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String("RegionCode",regionCode);

restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

How can I add rest two fields to header?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try the following:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.put("RegionCode", regionCode);
headers.put("SystemId", systemId);
headers.put("Locale", locale);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(body,headers);

restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(body,headers);    what is body in this line??

Comment: Its the body of the request. If it is not required (you just need the headers) you can leave it empty

Answer (score 0):

```
This is one of the example I have created:-

/********This is controller getMethod**********/

@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        System.out.println("Fetching Employee with id " + id);
        Employee user = employeeService.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("Employee with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


/********This is client implementation**********/

@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        System.out.println("Fetching Employee with id " + id);
        Employee user = employeeService.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("Employee with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
/*************Done**************/

/*******Output******/

<200 OK,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employee>
<age>33</age>
<id>1</id>
<name>Tomy</name>
<salary>70000.0</salary>
</employee>`enter code here`
,{Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[*], Access-Control-Allow-Methods=[POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE], Access-Control-Max-Age=[3600], Access-Control-Allow-Headers=[x-requested-with], Content-Type=[application/xml], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Date=[Wed, 20 Apr 2016 12:49:16 GMT]}>
```